# Can't generate allure report in Linux Jenkins server

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, allure

Allure does not generate reports on a linux jenkins server. The same is working on a MAC jenkins server. Can anybody suggest?

Below is the error:

> ```
> Invalid tool ID 
>
> ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception:  
> java.io.IOException: Can't find allure commandline <null> 
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation$2.call(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:63)
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation$2.call(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:58)
> at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation.getMajorVersion(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:58)
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.ReportBuilder.build(ReportBuilder.java:43)
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:171)
> at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:94)
> at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
> at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
> at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you have configured "Allure commandline installations" to not install automatically; so have you downloaded and installed Allure to a directory on the linux filesystem?

This is telling: "java.io.IOException: Can't find allure commandline"